# MKMapView setVisibleMapRect edgePadding changes Camera heading when Animating

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview

I am animating the MKMapView by adjusting the edgePadding; however when doing the animation the Map is **rotated during the animation** and the existing camera heading of the mapView is lost during the animation.

Restoring the heading is not ideal; And setting the camera heading during the animation breaks the animation and no animation is performed; the orientation persists but the offsets are not animated.

The code snippet below has the effect of animating the maps offset, except that the map heading is flipped; when the animation completes I fix the heading.

I want the map views heading to stay as it is and only animate the offset
when adjusting the MKMapView's inset, which is being animated.

*please assist*

```
self.mapView.rotateEnabled = YES;
self.mapView.camera.heading = deg;

[MKMapView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    // top, left, bottom, right
    self.mapView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(y, 0, -y, 0);
    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.mapView visibleMapRect]
                        edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.offset, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                           animated:YES];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.mapView.camera.heading = deg;
    self.mapView.rotateEnabled = NO;
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution by capturing the MkMapViews current camera
and setting the MKMapViews camera during the animation.

```
MKMapCamera *mapCamera = [[self.mapView camera] copy]; // the fix 1 of 2   
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    // top, left, bottom, right
    self.mapView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(y, 0, -y, 0);
    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.mapView visibleMapRect]
                        edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.offset, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                           animated:YES];
    [self.mapView setCamera:mapCamera]; // the fix 2 of 2
}];
```